# Suppress "in" for articles, modify for inbooks

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, delimiters

I want articles to appear as

> Kowalski Jan, "Reforma reformatorska", Przeglad Historyczny 1 (1953), pp. 101-152.

Inbook and incollection must appears as

> Kwiatkowska Anna, "Liczenie dla dzieci" [in:] Studia matematyczne,Warszawa:
> DiG, 2014, pp. 247-272.

Please pay attention on delimiters in both cases (comma before journal title for articles, and no comma before and after "in" for inbooks).

My code looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}

%comma instead of dot as default delimiter
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

%no comma between first name and last name
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\setunit{\space}%
       \printtext{%
       %\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{in}\addcolon}}}}
       \bibstring{in}\addcolon}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{a1,
          author        ={Kowalski, Jan},
          title         ={Reforma reformatorska},
          journaltitle  ={Przeglad Historyczny},
          date          ={1953},
          number        ={1},
          pages         ={101-152},
    }
@inbook{b1,
  author        ={Kwiatkowska, Anna},
  location      ={Warszawa},
  publisher     ={DiG},
  booktitle     ={Studia matematyczne},
  title         ={Liczenie dla dzieci},
  pages         ={247-272},
  date          ={2014},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
a\footcite{a1}

b\footcite{b1}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Everything would be fine if I didn't need the parentheses. But if I use `\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{in}\addcolon}` instead of `\bibstring{in}\addcolon` there is redundant comma after `[in:]`. How can I remove that comma after `[in:]` and preserve everything else?

Result with brackets and redundant comma:

[image: with_brackets]

Result without comma but also without brackets:
[image: no_brackets]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your solution of `in:` you were just missing a way to make sure that the punctuation printed after the "[in:]" is always a space. That could be done with `\printunit{\addspace}`. Note that `\printunit` is also used in the current standard definition of `in:` ([ll. 2927-2929 of `biblatex.def`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/062d48e3ab7374ff9b2a3c1503934924c917528a/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L2927-L2929)), your redefinition seems to have been based on an older version of `in:`.

Based on the new code and following the principle that one should never have a bare `\mkbibbrackets` in a bibmacro I suggest

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\setunit{\addspace}%
     \printtext[brackets]{%
       \bibstring{in}%
       \addcolon}%
     \printunit{\addspace}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{a1,
  author        = {Kowalski, Jan},
  title         = {Reforma reformatorska},
  journaltitle  = {Przeglad Historyczny},
  date          = {1953},
  number        = {1},
  pages         = {101-152},
}
@inbook{b1,
  author        = {Kwiatkowska, Anna},
  location      = {Warszawa},
  publisher     = {DiG},
  booktitle     = {Studia matematyczne},
  title         = {Liczenie dla dzieci},
  pages         = {247-272},
  date          = {2014},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{a1}

ipsum \autocite{b1}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Kowalski Jan, “Reforma reformatorska”, Przeglad Historyczny 1 (1953), pp. 101–152. Kwiatkowska Anna, “Liczenie dla dzieci” [in:] Studia matematyczne, Warszawa: DiG, 2014, pp. 247–272.]

Comment: You are absolutely reliable. Thanks!